# Stochastic differential of $Y(t) := \int_{-\infty}^0 X(t+s)\,\mathrm{e}^{\lambda\,s}\,\mathrm{d}s$

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

It is claimed in a lecture notes that the stochastic differential of $$Y(t) := \int_{-\infty}^0 X(t+s)\,\mathrm{e}^{\lambda\,s}\,\mathrm{d}s,$$ where $(X(t))_{t \in \mathbb R}$ is a $\mathbb R$-valued stochastic process, is given by $$\mathrm{d}Y(t) = \left(X(t) - \lambda Y(t)\right)\mathrm{d}t. $$ May I know how to derive the advertised SDE satisfied by $Y(t)$?

---

Edit: The precise source of my question is coming from page 5 of [this lecture notes](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Escheutzow/Lecture_Notes_SDDEs.pdf). It seems that if $X(t)$ is a ordinary differentiable function, the derivation is easy. But we might need to be more careful in case $X(t)$ is an Ito process...

Comment: why "close"? this is definitely not an obvious question...

Comment: I can't rigorously argue until I have your notes and your notation ,but extremely roughly, if I treat $X,Y$ as functions, then $\frac{Y(t+h) - Y(t))}{h}$ equals $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{X(t+h+s) - X(t+s)}{h} e^{\lambda s} ds$. If we allow ourselves to take $\lim_{h \to 0}$ now, then the LHS will be (roughly) $Y'(t)$ while the RHS, if I allow myself to switch the limit with the integral , is $\int_{-\infty}^0 X'(t+s)e^{\lambda s}ds$, whence if we do an integration-by-parts we get $X(t) - \int_{-\infty}^0 \lambda X(t+s)e^{\lambda s}ds$ etc. Now we need to bring rigour in.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you my old friend (in MSE forum)! I have included the source of material which is directly related to my question, your "integration-by-parts" step might need to be made more rigorous if $X(t)$ is an Ito process...

Comment: You are welcome! I think I can make it rigorous, but I've got some work to do now so I'll get back and definitely get on this case soon!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Y(t) = e^{-\lambda t} \int_{-\infty}^0 X(t+s) e^{\lambda(t+s)} d(s+t) = e^{-\lambda t} \int_{-\infty}^t X(u) e^{\lambda u} d u$

Notice that the last integral is defined path-by-path in the classical sense (i.e. no Ito integral is needed).  Therefore, $Y(t)$ is of finite variation and actually differential as a function of $t$.

From here, take the derivative of $Y$ against $t$ and the rest follows easily.

Comment: thank you very much! One question though: can you elaborate more on the point that $Y(t)$ is of finite variation?

Comment: For the last integral, if it can be defined in the classical sense for each sample path of $X$, then the $Y(t)$ is a stochastic process with each sample path being differentiable.  Being differential already implies finite variation.  (You can ignore the finite variation part.  I was just typing as I was thinking and probably should have edited that out.)

Comment: Thank you very much!